# Return ID of last inserted row in PostgreSQL with RETURNING clause

Tags: postgresql

I've got a pretty simple function defined like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_new_order(....) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    PERFORM add_points_to_usage(client_id_p, date_in_p, total_points_p);

INSERT INTO orders (...) VALUES (...)
    RETURNING ident;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Where I'm struggling is how to actually RETURN the value stored in the `ident` field back via the RETURNING clause.  I've tried setting the value to a variable but that either doesn't work or I'm just messing up the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the variable declaration, the `INTO` clause and the final `RETURN`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_new_order(....) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  var_ident int;
BEGIN
    PERFORM add_points_to_usage(client_id_p, date_in_p, total_points_p);
    INSERT INTO orders (...) VALUES (...)
       RETURNING ident INTO var_ident;
    RETURN var_ident;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```